# Dojo Dtl if conition logic not working

Tags: if-statement, dojo, dtls

Please suggest to define if condition in DOJO DTL

Ex:

```
{% if item.Status == "Pending" %}
Your coding
{% else %}
```

This is not working

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
{% ifequal item.status "Pending" %}
```